# Matlab: Slide through images stored in a cell array

Tags: matlab, user-interface, cell, imshow

First time working with matlab gui and I might not use the correct terms.

I have a 1x50 cell in my working directory called images. Each cell contains a 100x100 double image. I want to display one image at a time and be able to scroll through the images. So I'd like to have some sort of slider in the range k=1:50.

Is there a way to achieve this without saving the images?

All I have till now:

```
f = figure;
p = uipanel(f,'Position',[0.1 0.1 0.35 0.65]);
c = uicontrol(p, 'Style', 'slider', 'value', 1, ...
                'min', 1, 'max', k, 'SliderStep', [1 1]/(k - 1));
```

Comment: Yes... but this question is too broad

Comment: Why is it too broad and how could I specify it?

Comment: Your question is "I want to make a GUI to do X", you need to invest some time trying to create this GUI, perhaps make a demo which loads a single image, add a slider, work out how to use the slider's `Callback` property, and how to get the slider value, then how to use this value to look at a 2nd image. With all that knowledge you will have learnt how to do this yourself and not require this question. Any specific part I've listed here would be an appropriate thing to search Google for, and ask a question about. Currently we can't tell what you don't know how to do, and we won't do all of "X"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I am actually failing at the first step: loading images(1) from the working directory. I was only able to find examples which open some saved images from /home/...... . That’s why I asked  for a way without saving the images.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `imread` function? You just pass it a file path... if the file is in the working directory then the only difference is you only need the file name, not the full path (although the full path still works)